# What are the implications of an infinite series of inaccessible cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, large-cardinals

I saw a question where it was asked of the implications of two inaccessible cardinals and wondered about the implications of an infinite series of inaccessible cardinals. I also am wondering of how they vary from which infinity you chose for the quantity of elements. It is clear that everything implied from 2 inaccessibles rolls over on to this question, so that is okay to leave out, because I can always look at the original question for the rest of the implications.

Comment: I mean, really not that much more. There's the obvious generalisations from the 2 inaccessible cardinals. But in effect, there's not much difference between 2, 3, or infinitely many inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: It gets somewhat more interesting with a proper class of inaccessible cardinals, then you get that every set belongs to a Grothendieck universe